Why didn't the Empire capture rebel droids and extract their memories?
During "Rogue One", K-2SO forcibly reads the memory of another security droid to get a    map of the Scarif complex.
Given this ability, why would the Empire not capture Rebel droids and extract their memories as an interrogation alternative?
Literally capturing any of the X-wings that the Rebels deployed to Scarif to mind-rip one of the astromechs for their navigational history would tell them the location of the Rebel Base.
Seems like a memory extraction on this droid could pretty give them the location of the Rebel Base a lot easier than human interrogation:

Just to get ahead of the "The Empire always underestimates droids" answer, there is another droid on the Tantive IV that was hacked by the Empire, allowing Darth Vader to find where the Tantive IV escaped after the Battle of Scarif.  So, there is canon precedent for the Empire understanding droids are a useful intelligence asset.

You've said "why don't they", then immediately given an example where they have and they do

@Valorum I interpreted that as "why don't they routinely"

Hesitant to make this an answer as it's only speculative, but Star Wars: The Clone Wars establishes that Republic forces are supposed to memory-wipe their droids after every mission to prevent that exact scenario. It's possible that the Rebels do the same thing, and/or most Imperials expect them to and therefore don't bother checking the droids.

@Valorum In the example I provided, they hacked the droid to act on their behalf.  I can't find examples of them trying to capture droids for the purpose of stealing their memories.

It's all down to software licensing agreements.

At least in current canon, they do. In issue 26 of the 2015 Star Wars comic series, C-3PO is captured by several stormtroopers, who try to get intel out of him through interrogation:

One trooper proposes reading C-3PO's memory banks, but Vader orders him destroyed instead:

The comic doesn't spell it out, but it's possible Vader recognizes C-3PO and just wants the reminder of his past gone. Either way, it appears that interrogating and scanning Rebel droids is common practice for the Empire. As for why they don't make it a higher priority than capturing and interrogating Rebel personnel (if in fact they don't), I haven't seen it addressed anywhere.
